# Euler loop list

Tags: python, math, physics

I want to plot a rocket trajectory with a loop using Euler's method. My code is(you can skip this, the error is below it):

```
mo = 1000
m = 900
q = 2.8
u = 3700
vo = 0
xo = 0.0001
g = 9.81
t = np.arange(0,int(1001))
x0 = 0.0001
v0 = 0
N = 1000
at = 1/1000
```

Now velocity and height equations:

```
def v(t):
    return  u*np.log(mo/(mo-q*t))-g*t

def az(t):
    return xo + vo*t - 0.5*g*t**2 + u*t*np.log(mo) + (u/q)*((mo - q*t)*np.log(mo 
    - q*t) + q*t - mo*np.log(mo))

z = xo + vo*t - 0.5*g*t**2 + u*t*np.log(mo) + (u/q)*((mo - q*t)*np.log(mo 
- q*t) + q*t - mo*np.log(mo))
```

And here is the acceleration which I turned into a list because of the error:

```
aj = -g + (q/(mo-q*t))*u
ajj = np.array(aj).tolist()
```

So here is the loop where I am trying to solve it in an analytic way with Euler's method:

```
t = np.zeros(N + 1)
t[0] = 0
z = np.zeros(N + 1)
z[0] = x0

v = np.zeros(N + 1)

v[0] = 0


for k in range(0,N):
    v[k + 1] = v[k] +ajj*z[k]*at
    z[k + 1] = z[k] + v[k + 1]*at
```

And it gives me this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-d1513ed52aa0> in <module>()
 11 
 12 for k in range(0,N):
 ---> 13     v[k + 1] = v[k] + ajj*z[k]*at
 14     z[k + 1] = z[k] + v[k + 1]*at
 15 

 ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I know what it barely means. The error is because of the list ajj but I don't know how to fix it in order to plot z along the time. Thanks for helping. Sorry for the long question I'm just starting programming.

Comment: Put your code together, not pieces.

Comment: `ajj` is a `list` and `z[0]` is a `float`, what do you expect `ajj * z[k]` to equal? You have a lot of code that is not germane to your issue, please try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: idk it´s 4 in the morning and I fcked up sorry I just want to plot the rocket trajectory with a loop using euler´s method

Comment: @Syzy That's not how it works on SO.

Comment: @Syzy A general "help me" post might be appropriate for a forum or a chat board or something less structured, but questions on Stack Overflow are held to a higher standard. A good question here is *very specific* about a particular part of programming, after you've boiled away everything not directly related to the specific programming problem. This refining process is good for Stack Overflow questions, but more importantly it's *a key skill* in programming: cut the problem into smaller and smaller pieces until you understand *exactly* what the problem is. Much easier to solve a small problem!

Comment: I'd recommend writing an Euler integration scheme and testing it with some simple function that you know the answer to (e.g. f(x) = x or something else from elementary integral calculus).  Decompose your problem into pieces.  Get one working and then move onto the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODE system is `m'(t)=-q, az'(t)=v(t), v'(t)=u*q/m(t)-g`, here with inserting `m(t)=m0-q*t`. It always helps to separate the system dynamics from the solver via an ODE function,

```
def ODEfunc(t,y): az, v = y; return np.array([ v, -g+q*u/(m0-q*t) ]);
```

so that you can then iterate the Euler steps as per cook book formula

```
t, y = t+h, y + h*ODEfunc(t,y)
```